# Amazon SES: email address cannot be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email via Amazon SES.

I have `MX` record for `mydomain.com` as shown below:

```
$ dig mx mydomain.com +noall +answer +nocomments

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> mx mydomain.com +noall +answer +nocomments
;; global options: +cmd
mydomain.com.       2719    IN  MX  10 inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.
```

However, when sending to e.g. `someone@mydomain.com`, I get:

> The email address you entered couldn't be found. Please check the recipient's email address and try to resend the message. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

I also have a hosted zone for `mydomain.com`

What should I  do for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you configure SES to receive email? Where are you telling SES to send your received emails?

This document will help you understand receiving email via SES:

[Receiving Email with Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html)